# Viz charts: How to set Scale of valueAxis to Auto

Tags: charts, sapui5, sap-fiori

I need to set the scale for `valueAxis` to auto i.e. without mentioning `min` and `max` in `setVizScales` method.
Is there any way we can use https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.chart.ScaleBehavior` in Viz chart.

So that values with small differences can be placed away from each other unlike one in the below image

[image]

```
valueAxisScale: {
    scaleBehavior: sap.chart.ScaleBehavior,
    autoScaleSettings: {
        syncWith: sap.chart.AutoScaleMode.VisibleData
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. in the xml file you define a VizFrame:

```
<viz:VizFrame id="idVizFrame" uiConfig="{applicationSet:'fiori'}"
height='100%' width="100%" vizType='line'>
<viz:VizFrame>
```

2. in js file you initial the VizFrame:

```
onInit: function (evt) {

    var oVizFrame = this.oVizFrame = this.getView().byId("idVizFrame");
    oVizFrame.setVizProperties({
        plotArea: {
            dataLabel: {
                formatString: formatPattern.SHORTFLOAT_MFD2,
                visible: true
            }
        },
        valueAxis: {
            label: {
                formatString: formatPattern.SHORTFLOAT
            },
            title: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        valueAxisScale: "AutoScale",
        categoryAxis: {
            title: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        title: {
            visible: false,
            text: 'Revenue by City and Store Name'
        }
    });
}
```

in the js code you can see the option:

```
valueAxisScale: "AutoScale"
```

Comment: I tried `AutoScale` but still plotted values are close to each other as in the above image, can you tell me what should be done so that they placed at distant from each other for a different range of values without hardcoding anything specific number

Comment: what kind of chart are you using?

Comment: Viz Chart-Line I have added code, I have added `synchWith` property but that is not working as well